# Pick the latest Partition from the interval partition

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

I have a table which has interval partition.

```
    CREATE TABLE interval_tab (
  id           NUMBER,
  code         VARCHAR2(10),
  description  VARCHAR2(50),
  created_date DATE
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (created_date)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'day'))
(
   PARTITION part_01 values LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-NOV-2017','DD-MON-YYYY'))
);
```

Data gets loaded into this table everyday in new partition and I need to pick the data from the latest partition. How do I query to get the data from the latest partition ?

Thank you!

Comment: You could just have a predicate of `where created_date >= trunc(sysdate)`, assuming you're going to be querying the table once today's data has been loaded into it.

Comment: Thank you Boniest for responding. My table has huge set of data( millions of millions records getting inserted everyday )  and I feel it is good to select from the partition rather than the whole table. What do you suggest if this is the case?

Comment: Why do you feel that is good; do you have a reason to think Oracle won't pick the right partition, or won't do it efficiently? Or do you want the most recent partition regardless of whether today's data has been loaded? It isn't clear what problem you are really trying to solve.

Comment: Oracle's optimizer has a thing it can do called "partition pruning". That is, it is clever enough to look at the query's predicates and work out what partitions it needs to look in. If you have a predicate on the partition key (i.e. my suggestion of `where created_date >= trunc(sysdate)`, or maybe `where created_date >= trunc(sysdate) and created_date < trunc(sysdate) + 1`; you'd have to experiement to see which one works best in your situation), the optimizer should be able to query the specific partition(s) necessary, rather than the whole table.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle should be able to determine the partition to use based on your query predicate.  If you selected data for just the current day, Oracle should do something like this:

```
create table test_data (
   id           NUMBER,
   code         VARCHAR2(10),
   description  VARCHAR2(50),
   created_date      DATE default sysdate not null
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (created_date)
INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'day'))
(
   PARTITION part_01 values LESS THAN (TO_DATE('20180627','YYYYMMDD'))
);

insert into test_data values (1,'A','A code',sysdate-3);
insert into test_data values (1,'B','B code',sysdate-2);
insert into test_data values (1,'C','C code',sysdate-1);
insert into test_data values (1,'D','D code',sysdate);
insert into test_data values (1,'E','E code',sysdate);

commit;

select * from test_data
where created_date >= trunc(sysdate);
```

Output:

```
ID  CODE    DESCRIPTION CREATED_DATE
1   D   D code  6/27/2018 9:11:07 AM
1   E   E code  6/27/2018 9:11:07 AM
```

Explain plan looks like:

```
Plan
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWS
Cost: 4  Bytes: 168  Cardinality: 3         
    2 PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR  
    Cost: 4  Bytes: 168  Cardinality: 3  Partition #: 1  Partitions determined by Key Values    
        1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE TEST_DATA 
        Cost: 4  Bytes: 168  Cardinality: 3  Partition #: 1  Partitions determined by Key Values
```

You can also add indexes (local or global) depending on your situation and needs.

**Note**:  You can also use the "partition for" clause to choose data from a partition without knowing its name (esp useful in interval partitioning).  For example:

```
select * from test_data partition for (to_date('20180627','YYYYMMDD'));
```